# Plex and OwnCloud: permission and multi-user

Tags: permissions, owncloud, plex

I have installed Owncloud on my server and Plex to manage audio and video files. I have successfully added owncloud folder data to plex (add plex user to www-data group), but in this way I can access to ALL users folder, not only my folder. 
There is a way to "sync" owncloud and plex users, so that a user can add to his library only its owncloud folders?

Thanks!
Roberto